# How to handle stale pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, heap-memory

We are incrementing a reference count to perform certain things.

```
m_pObjPoolMem->tlIncrementBaseRefCount()
```

Certain scenario might occur where `m_pObjPoolMem` could be NULL or released memory. NULL pointer can be easily handled by checking `if (m_pObjPoolMem != NULL)`. But how to handle if the pointer is holding released memory.

In case if the code is called with released memory it could lead to the following error

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.**this** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBF.
```

How to handle this scenario

Comment: If  `m_pObjPoolMem` is not `NULL` why was the memory released? Since it reference counted, shouldn't only the last teference to the memory release the memory?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a `weak_ptr<>` equivalent for your hand-rolled ref-counting system.

Comment: Ensure the pointer ceases to exist as soon as possible after the object it points at - a pointer that no longer exists cannot be accidentally dereferenced.  There are numerous ways to achieve that in C++. One is to place the pointer in an object that passes out of scope, and its destructor destroys the pointee (the pointer will no longer exist after the destructor returns). Using standard containers, smart pointers, etc from the standard library allows avoiding using pointers (directly) at all, which makes it harder to have a pointer pointing at something that no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the code without having a valid pointer. Document that it is a pre-condition for this code that the pointer be valid or NULL. Make sure this is enforced in every caller.

Lots of code has pre-conditions that must be met for the code's behavior to be defined. This should be a pre-condition of your code.

Comment: yeah right. But how to check whether it is a valid pointer

Comment: @Rayner You don't check. You simply document that it must be and shift that responsibility onto the code that provides the pointer to this code. If this code needs to know information about the pointer, the code that provides the pointer has to tell it.